# Slave not getting replicated SERVER_UUID error

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, linux, mysql-5.6

Unable to start replication Master-Slave, I have searched a lot for this but unable to get the `Server-UUID` of both the server. Do we have any solution for this.

Scenario: I have created new slave which is not getting replicated and we are getting error `Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because a fatal error is encountered when it tries to get the value of SERVER_UUID variable from master`.

On my slave I have `auto.cnf` which is having `SERVER_UUID` but the Master doesn't have. I think if because of this we are facing problem. if i am able to generate this on Master my replication will start.

Both on `Centos 6.7`
Master Version `MySQL-server-5.5.41-1.el6.x86_64`
Slave1 Version `Mysql-community-server-5.7.10-2.el6.x86_64`
Slave2 running absolutely fine on `MySQL-server-5.6.25-1.el6.x86_64`

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State:
                  Master_Host: 10.10.2.12
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000089
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 18646782
               Relay_Log_File: GACRMDATA2-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000089
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 18646782
              Relay_Log_Space: 150
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1593
                Last_IO_Error: Fatal error: The slave I/O thread stops because a fatal error is encountered when it tries to get the value of SERVER_UUID variable from master.
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 212
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 160201 09:41:40
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

output of `my.cnf` for reference

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
innodb_file_per_table=0
innodb_checksum_algorithm=INNODB
binlog_checksum=NONE
server-id = 216
tmpdir=/tmp/mysqltemp

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

log-bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
general_log=1
slow_query_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysqld-gen.log
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1
binlog_format=MIXED
long_query_time=3

#INNODB SETTINGS
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 107G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=50
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 1G  (Initially this gave an error) 
innodb_thread_concurrency=0
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size = 100M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=400
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=10
innodb_open_files=1000

bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
thread_cache_size=128M
#table_cache = 2000
table_open_cache = 4096
interactive_timeout = 600
wait_timeout=1000
join_buffer_size = 3M
sort_buffer_size = 8M
max_connections = 600
key_buffer_size = 1G
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
lock_wait_timeout=500
transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED
max_allowed_packet=512M
tmp_table_size=32M
event_scheduler=1
open_files_limit=20000
default_storage_engine=innodb
group_concat_max_len=1M
preload_buffer_size=33554432
net_buffer_length=1048576
symbolic-links=0
sync_binlog=1

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Slave2 output `show slave status\G`

```
[(none)]> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.10.2.12
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000093
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 8641342
               Relay_Log_File: relay-bin.000008
                Relay_Log_Pos: 8641501
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000093
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 8641342
              Relay_Log_Space: 8643392
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 212
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave                                                     I/O thread to update it
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the following links:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79272

https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/43922-fatal-error-trying-to-sync-percona-5-7-slave-to-mysql-5-5-master

Seems like you need to upgrade to 5.6 prior to replicating to 5.7 from 5.5. Too bad, the documentation is so cryptic

" MySQL supports replication from one release series to the next higher release series. For example, you can replicate from a master running MySQL 5.5 to a slave running MySQL 5.6, from a master running MySQL 5.6 to a slave running MySQL 5.7, and so on.

However, you may encounter difficulties when replicating from an older master to a newer slave ...."